# Reality Composer USDZ Animation with Other animations

Tags: arkit, reality-composer

I have a USDZ file that has capabilities to do some animations by itself. If I create two behaviours in Reality Composer, one to start the USDZ animation and other one for Moving the object itself from one point to the other, the object does not move. However If I remove the behaviour of the USDz animation and just leave the moving one, it works perfectly.

So my question is, Is a bug by apple? Or I am missing something. I want to be able to make a character move his legs while moving from point to the other.

Thanks

Comment: Bumped into the same problem. Seems like a bug from Apple, because it was working before. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I discovered was to increase the number of iterations in the USDZ animation action sequence.
I don't quite understand the concept of iterations in here, because even on 1, the animation is looped. Increased it to 100 and was able to combine animations